# How to insert letters in a "word"?

Tags: code-request

I have:

```
 list = {{1, AGR}, {2, AUS}, {3, AUT}};
```

but I want the following using `Table[.]`.

```
mmARG = mmB[1];
mmAUS = mmB[2];
mmAUT = mmB[3];
```

Any idea?

Comment: This looks very much like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What are you trying to achieve ultimately?

Comment: @Roman: My purpose is to create a new variable without writing the same equation 250 times. There is a pattern between integer number and the suffix of a variable name. I wanted to use this relation to create 250 equations with new variable names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this will do what you want. But it generates what you show.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
list = {{1, AGR}, {2, AUS}, {3, AUT}};
tbl = MapIndexed[ToExpression[("mm" <> ToString[#1[[2]]])] == 
     ToExpression["mmB[" <> ToString@First[#2] <> "]"] &, list];
TableForm[tbl]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you wan `Set` istead of `Equal`, change the above to

```
list = {{1, AGR}, {2, AUS}, {3, AUT}};
tbl = MapIndexed[{ToExpression[("mm" <> ToString[#1[[2]]])], 
     ToExpression["mmB[" <> ToString@First[#2] <> "]"]} &, list];
Set @@@ tbl
```

And now

[image: Mathematica graphics]

etc...

If you want to use `Set` for display, then evaluate it later, you can do

```
list = {{1, AGR}, {2, AUS}, {3, AUT}};
tbl = MapIndexed[("mm" <> ToString[#1[[2]]] <> " = " <> "mmB[" <> 
      ToString@First[#2] <> "]") &, list];
TableForm[tbl]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But the above is string. To Make it actual Mathematica `Set`, need to use

```
ToExpression[tbl]
```

And now the assignment is made.

**Answer comment**

> making the same operation with the following

You could try

```
Clear["Global`*"]
list = {{1, AGR}, {2, AUS}, {3, AUT}};
tbl = MapIndexed[("mm" <> ToString[#1[[2]]] <> " = " <> "mmB[" <> 
     ToString@First[#2] <> "] - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[mmB[" <> 
     ToString@First[#2] <> "]]]") &, list]
TableForm[tbl]
```

Which gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But before applying `ToExpression` to the above, you would need to have those `mmB[i]` defined, else `Diagonal` will give error. It needs them to be lists.

Something like

```
mmB[1] = {1, 2, 3};
mmB[2] = {4, 5, 6};
mmB[3] = {7, 8, 9};
```

And only now you can do `ToExpression[tbl]`

Comment: Yes, I was writing to you that it should be `Set`, not `Equality`.

Comment: ok, the above does both. If you want to display the actual `Set`, then you have to Hold the expression. I am not sure if that is for display purposes you are doing this, otherwise you can just run `Set` on the whole list.

Comment: Actually, in the real context, I have `mmAGR = mmB[1] - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[mmB[1]]]`, `mmAUS = mmB[2] - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[mmB[2]]]` etc. Which are all calculations. Sorry for my revision.

Comment: Your Code gives the correct equalities, however, it does not give the result of the evaluations even after `TableForm[Evaluate[tbl]]`.

Comment: It works now. Do you mind also making the same operation with the following: `mmAGR = mmB[1] - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[mmB[1]]]`, `mmAUS = mmB[2] - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[mmB[2]]]` etc. Matrix operations should be conducted.

Comment: @TugrulTemel fyi, updated post.

Comment: It worked...Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's generally not a good idea to encode information in the variable name. Much more natural in Mathematica would be to encode the left-hand side as a pattern:

```
list = {{1, AGR}, {2, AUS}, {3, AUT}};
(mm[#[[2]]] = mmB[#[[1]]]) & /@ list;
```

The information is now stored as

```
?mm

(*    mm[AGR] = mmB[1]
      mm[AUS] = mmB[2]
      mm[AUT] = mmB[3]    *)
```

so the left-hand sides are `mm[AGR]` instead of your `mmAGR`. You can treat `mm[AGR]` as a regular variable.

The extended example works in the same way,

```
(mm[#[[2]]] = mmB[#[[1]]] - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[mmB[#[[1]]]]]) & /@ list;
```

Comment: It is a very good explanation. I chose the convenient route as I have written my Codes in `mmAGR` type variables. Next time when I write codes, I will certainly follow your suggestion.

Comment: Your answer was so appealing that I could not stand more and revised all my Code with your suggestion. Thanks very much for this.